# IOS - Load unknown type of UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, runtime

I'm trying to load UIViewController, but not knowing the type until runtime.

So I have some different UIViewControllers, each one with it's own .xib, and with the
following code, the .xib is showed correctly, but the UIViewController is never created, because
it's a child of UIViewController, not an exactly UIViewController:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[[self component] xibName] bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

It works fine for example in this particular case, but obviously not for the rest:

```
Controller1 *vc = [[Controller1 alloc] initWithNibName:[[self component] xibName] bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

How can I solve it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your controller classe name in an NSSTring and create the object like this 

`UIViewController *vc=[[NSClassFromString(ControllerclassName) alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`